# loading local audio file and play it with Audio()

Tags: javascript, html, file, audio, local

I'm trying to load local audio file by the (input:file) Elem and when I passe it to the audio constructor Audio() as an object it doesn't load/play.

**file Object params&meths:**

```
lastModified: 1586969070000
lastModifiedDate: Wed Apr 15 2020 18:44:30 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
name: "audio.mp3"
size: 15235482
type: "audio/mpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

i tried giving just the name, relative path but nothing seems to work.

**Js Code**

```
var track = new Audio(file Object);
track.play();
```

when I tried to troubleshoot:

```
console.log(track);

<audio preload="auto" src="[object File]">
#shadow-root (user-agent)
</audio>
```

and when play() triggered:

```
GET http:// **Local IP** /[object%20File] 404 (Not Found)
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

although before I started the project I did a little test and it worked perfectly but now it doesn't...
any help will be amazing thanks

Comment: `var track = new Audio(file Object);` - wrong way. You must insert URL into new Audio constructor, not file Object

Comment: @DimaVak
that's the point. I'm here loading a file with (input:file) so I don't have access to the real file URL although there is a relative one but it appears as an empty string ""...

Answer (score 1):

That works in another way.
You must add your file, after that catch his node(input), and from that create a URL. This URL work like a normal URL, but with your local files.

Sorry for that bad explanation, here you can read more

https://javascript.info/file
https://javascript.info/blob

Too I create a snippet. Chose local file -> Add SRC to "player' -> Click Play btn.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const yourMusic = document.querySelector("#yourMusic");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let music = document.querySelector("#file").files[0];
  yourMusic.src = URL.createObjectURL(music);
});
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
    <button id="btn">Add to player</button>
    <audio controls id="yourMusic"></audio>
```

Comment: Is it answer for your question?